# Should I choose datatype of keyword or long / integer for document personId in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with personId (which is an int in DB).

I am not sure should I choose `keyword` or `long` when creating the document in Elasticsearch?

And in terms of space and performance, what is the benefit and disadvantages for each of them? (I only find the difference between `text` and `keyword`, instead of `keyword` vs. `long`)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If your personId is an int in your DB, I would also pick the `long` type in ES.

`keyword` is more suitable for string data that you don't want to go through the analysis process and simply store as an exact value. There's no such thing with integer values, you simply want to store its exact value and that's exactly what the `long` type does.

Comment: Thanks for it. value is an int, what's the drawbacks from keyword compared to long? and what's the drawbacks from long compared to keyword? Sorry I still want to figure out the more difference and impact for these 2 types

Comment: well, as I've stated it already, keyword is for string data and you have a number. Numbers can be sorted numerically, while keywords are sorted lexically (i.e. 10 comes before 2, 3, 4, ...). If you need to do range queries or aggregations on that id, then a `long` will be more appropriate exactly for that reason. If you need to be able to search for (edge-)ngrams on those ids (i.e. by prefix, substring or suffix), then you'll need a `text` type with analysis. Nothing prevents you to have both, i.e. a long type and a sub-field as a keyword or analyzed string to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Val. Before I close this one, if I only take that field as another identity field. Either `long` or `keyword` will do the work? and I am still curious about both's performance (thought `long` ought to be better performance?)

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783054/what-is-the-most-suitable-datatype-to-use-in-aggregations-with-elasticsearch-5/40783182#40783182

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 43):

The fact that some data is numeric does not mean it should always be mapped as a numeric field. The way that Elasticsearch indexes numbers optimizes for range queries while keyword fields are better at term queries. Typically, fields storing identifiers such as an ISBN or any number identifying a record from another database are rarely used in range queries or aggregations. This is why they might benefit from being mapped as keyword rather than as integer or long.

Quoted from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#map-ids-as-keyword

Comment: i ran into this issue just yesterday. Searching thousands of `terms` that were integers performed more than 2x as fast using a keyword index vs using a number instead.

Comment: This should be the correct answer since the question specifically asks how identifiers should be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

One drawback of the long type is that it prevents you from using the Highlight feature.